# Malicious Software Removal Tool Requiring Elevated Permissions after Update

Tags: windows-update

I have a single user on my entire network that gets the issue described in the subject. Once a month M$ puts out the MSRT update and his computer gets the download. From that point on, every time he boots the computer he gets a prompt for credentials. No one has admin rights on my network, so he has no way to run the 1 scan other than calling me to approve with my admin creds. He is on a Surface Book running windows 10. Many others have the same setup but don't get this prompt. I'm wondering; is there's a way to allow MSRT to run without requiring the user to call support every time it updates?

I don't use WSUS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [runas tool](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-programs-as-administrator-without-password-windows/) or just allowing run-as privileges as in [this tutorial](https://www.maketecheasier.com/standard-users-run-program-admin-rights/)?

Comment: I would prefer a method that doesn't involve user intervention.